# Azure logic app authorization with custom policy issuer

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-logic-apps

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-securing-a-logic-app?tabs=azure-portal#:%7E:text=An%20authorization%20policy%20must%20include%20at%20least%20the%20Issuer%20claim%2C%20which%20has%20a%20value%20that%20starts%20with%20either%20https%3A//sts.windows.net/%20or%20https%3A//login.microsoftonline.com/%20(OAuth%20V2)%20as%20the%20Azure%20AD%20issuer%20ID.) states that an issuer has to be login.microsoftonline.com or sts.windows.net when securing a logic app. I have a custom policy where the issuer of the access token is https://{TENANT}.b2clogin.com/{TENANT}/v2.0. How can I secure a logic app using the access tokens that come back from my B2C custom policy?